# Extracting feature embeddings from an image

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to use TensorFlow.js to extract feature embeddings from images.

Elsewhere I'm using PyTorch and ResNet152 to extract feature embeddings to good effect.

The following is a sample of how I'm extracting those feature embeddings.

```py
import torch
import torchvision.models as models
from torchvision import transforms
from PIL import Image

# Load the model
resnet152_torch = models.resnet152(pretrained=True)

# Enumerate all of the layers of the model, except the last layer. This should leave
# the average pooling layer. 
layers = list(resnet152_torch.children())[:-1]

resnet152 = torch.nn.Sequential(*(list(resnet152_torch.children())[:-1]))

# Set to evaluation model. 
resnet152_torch.eval()

# Load and preprocess the image, it's already 224x224
image_path = "test.png" 
img = Image.open(image_path).convert("RGB")

# Define the image transformation
preprocess = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
])

# Apply the preprocessing steps to the image
img_tensor = preprocess(img).unsqueeze(0)

with torch.no_grad():
    # Get the image features from the ResNet-152 model
    img_features = resnet152(img_tensor)

print(img_features.squeeze())
```

Essentially, I'm using the pre-trained model and dropping the last layer to get my feature embeddings.

The result of the above script is:

```
tensor([0.2098, 0.4687, 0.0914,  ..., 0.0309, 0.0919, 0.0480])
```

So now, I want to do something similar with TensorFlow.js.

The first thing that I need is an instance of the ResNet152 model that I can use with TensorFlow.js. So I created the following Python script to export ResNet152 to the Keras format...

```py
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet152
from tensorflow.keras.models import save_model

# Load the pre-trained ResNet-152 model without the top (fully connected) layer
resnet152 = ResNet152(weights='imagenet')

# Set the model to evaluation mode
resnet152.trainable = False

# Save the ResNet-152 model
save_model(resnet152, "resnet152.h5")
```

And then I exported the Keras (.h5) model to the TensorFlow.js format using the "tensorflowjs_converter" utility...

```bash
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format keras resnet152.h5 resnet152
```

Once I have the model in the appropriate format (I think), I switch over to Javascript.

```js
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs-node';
import fs from 'fs';

async function main() {
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('file://resnet152/model.json');

    const modelWithoutFinalLayer = tf.model({
        inputs: model.input,
        outputs: model.getLayer('avg_pool').output
    });

    // Load the image from disk
    const image = fs.readFileSync('example_images/test.png'); // This is the exact same image file.
    const imageTensor = tf.node.decodeImage(image, 3);
    const preprocessedInput = tf.div(tf.sub(imageTensor, [123.68, 116.779, 103.939]), [58.393, 57.12, 57.375]);

    const batchedInput = preprocessedInput.expandDims(0);
    const embeddings = modelWithoutFinalLayer.predict(batchedInput).squeeze();

    embeddings.print();

    return;
}

await main();
```

The result of the above script is:

```bash
Tensor
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0.029606]
```

Looking at the first three values of the outputs between the two versions of the script, I expected there to be some variation but not THIS MUCH.

Where do I go from here? Is this much variation expected? Am I just doing this wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi tom, is it okay to give answer in straight tensorflow instead of tensorflow.js as it is not feasible get online environment for tf.js?

Comment: Hi @Innat, I'm really struggling with ts.js. If using straight tensorflow will get me closer to solving this though I'm open to try and adapt what you come up with.

Comment: There are few implementation differences to both models (torch and keras) and also how the pretrained weights are produced, some [details](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/15822#issuecomment-1027391270). I've just test both models, keeping the input same and able to reproduce the above cases. But I'm not sure which one to take as reference as both mdoels at th end give resonable scores independently.

Comment: The reported scores of torch's [`models.resnet152(weights='ResNet152_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V1')`](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/models/generated/torchvision.models.resnet152.html) is around same as keras' [ResNet152V2](https://keras.io/api/applications/) and not ResNet52V1.

Comment: Just to check some boxes. Are the python preprocessing steps of the image exactly the same as that of your java implementation? One is normalizing with some fixed mean/std and the other is a sub and divide? Which doesnt seem like normalization as RGB is 0-255 per channel right?

Comment: I can ensure that even with same input tensor, the outcomes from both models are different. As mentioned, there might be a high chance it's a weight issue. I raised a ticket in github. https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/18810

Comment: @Tombatron Despite having difference in feat embed in both torch and keras model, did you also not get expected output (of your main task) with keras model? The thing is that, torch weight is not translated to keras or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

The associated [Keras issue 18810 "Differences in feature embeddings in Keras and torch models"](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/18810) was just closed with:

> The first thing to check is whether you have the right preprocessing. The best practice is to always use `keras.applications.xxxx.preprocess_input`, in this case [`keras.applications.resnet.preprocess_input`](https://keras.io/api/applications/resnet/).
>
> I would not expect intermediate features or predictions to necessarily be close, because many of the models were retrained from scratch.

You issue might have partly came from differences in how the images are preprocessed before being fed into the models. By standardizing the preprocessing step using the recommended method for Keras models, you could make sure the input is in the optimal format for that specific model, reducing one potential source of discrepancy.

Regarding your concern about the significant variation in the feature embeddings between the PyTorch and Keras models, different implementations of the same model architecture (like ResNet152 in this case) might not produce closely similar intermediate features or predictions.
Many models in different frameworks are retrained from scratch, leading to differences in learned features despite having the same architecture.

That would help to understand that such variations in outputs are common and expected due to differences in the training process, even when the underlying architecture is the same.